# Failed to install pip requirements for Python 2.7 gear

Tags: python, openshift

I just created a Python 2.7 gear on Openshift and I am trying to deploy a Flask application. However it fails to install all the requirements.

I am seeing the following errors in the console after the deployment:

```
The directory '/var/lib/openshift/XYZ/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

You are using pip version 7.1.0, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.

The repository located at mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com is not a trusted or secure host and is being ignored. If this repository is available via HTTPS it is recommended to use HTTPS instead, otherwise you may silence this warning and allow it anyways with '--trusted-host mirror1.ops.rhcloud.com'.

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas==0.15.1
```

Please advice.

Comment: The symptoms are similar to the bug described here:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1307233#c0

Comment: I've filed a bug: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1361755